# Trouble with LIKE MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I have the following MySQL query that I execute from a .php page

```
SELECT * FROM servers WHERE name LIKE '%$value%'
```

which, when executed, selects 0 rows (However, the query runs successfully, so I can't use mysql_error() to debug). When I run the query in PHPMyAdmin it selects the appropriate rows. Other queries such as

```
SELECT * FROM servers
```

work fine. I can put my code up here if it will help.

Comment: so what are you having a problem with?

Comment: It would help to see the code you're talking about. Also, it doesn't hurt to get in the habit of [quoting your identifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html).

Comment: I'm implementing a search into my website, so $value is a string of characters. And yes, it goes through mysql_real_escape_string() and stripslashes().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit:* Here's something offering an improvement based on Marek's answer below. Please see the comments regarding the practice of putting variables directly into queries and consider using prepared statements. Anyway, here it goes.

1. PHP substitutes variables inside doubly-quoted strings, but not inside singly-quoted strings.
2. One quote character is just treated as an ordinary character within a string delimited by the other.

Putting that together, you can write:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM servers WHERE name LIKE '%$value%'"; //Fine
```

You cannot write:

```
$p = 'SELECT * FROM servers WHERE name LIKE "%$value%"'; //Broken!
```

`$q` works because it's a doubly-quoted string, and the apostrophes are just ordinary characters. `$p` does not work because it's a singly-quoted string.

As pointed out by GoodFather below, you can also say `${value}` to avoid ambiguities with the ambient string, e.g. `$r = "ABC${value}DEF";`.

Comment: @yes123: Did you test it? Works fine for me!

Comment: @yes123: That wasn't the question. For all we know the OP has `$value = mysql_real_escapestring($data, $link);` or something like that in place.

Comment: for all we know he has mysql_real_escape? lol and how do you know that? And even if you know he has that you should suggest him to use PDO. ALWAYS.

Comment: oh, you're smart enough to create your own answer puzzled from others answers.. mmmm

Comment: @yes: yes yes, fine, but that really wasn't the point of the question... do leave a comment for the OP though, of course.

Comment: even if it's not the point of the question yuo should never suggest him to put $var into SQL.

Comment: @yes: you're right of course -- why not write your own answer to suggest that? Marek: Sorry, I sort of meant this to be a correction to your original answer, but it got away from me... I'll take off the down-vote!

Comment: @yes: Hey, you get reputation for having upvoted answers, why _wouldn't_ you do it? ;-)

Comment: @Kerrek, sure, I appreciate your straightness, i did the same for you

Answer (score 0):

You really need to look at doing this query more safely.  This will help with your issue as well.  As it stands, you are vulnerable to SQL injection.  Look at the examples from the PHP manual for how to do it right:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

**EDIT**:  From your comments you mentioned that you are already taking care of the string properly, which is great.  The code below should fix your problem.

For example, you could rewrite your query statement (in PHP) like so:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM servers WHERE name LIKE '%". mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "%'");
```

That will clean up your code and it will also handle the issue with your LIKE statement not working properly.

Here is another good article on the subject:

http://joshhighland.com/blog/2008/07/06/php-sprintf-sql-like/

Comment: that doesn't answer his question, code security rules won't solve his syntax problems. If this is part of internal script administration, there is no security risk at all

Comment: @Marek - I was updating my answer with a code example to further explain it when you posted this comment.  As for your opinion on using this as an internal script with no danger, my opinion is that you NEVER write vulnerable code.  Even if it is used internally now, there may come a day when the code's purpose is changed.  Also, even internal code should be protected from these types of issues.  Who knows what junior admin actually executes this script.  They could cause real damage if you aren't careful.  Doing it right the first time is always better.

Comment: agree with you, but there is no need to focus on code vulnerability when you need to create code that works. Security and optimization is part of further steps, after you create working system. Of course I agree with need of secure and that we cannot say how he use this code now, but not working and SECURE code is unusable ;)

Comment: @Marek - I understand.  I just get real twitchy when I see something like that.  There are just so many ways that can go wrong.  This is especially true when we are posting code to a site like this.  Even if the OP is handling the code properly (he is), someone else who has a similar issue might not be.  It is my preference to have secure code that doesn't work vs. unsecure code that works (can you tell I'm responsible for data safety? :)  It seems like something always comes up and the good intentions to fix the security issues get forgotten because "it works".  That's been my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting a case-sensitive or case-insensitive query? I'm betting case-insensitive since you're expecting results but not seeing them. Take a look at your database's default collation or the table's specific collation and make sure it ends in _ci, whatever it is.